# HTML CSS 2 radio buttons toggle style

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have 2 radio buttons that are meant to toggle between each other when pressed.

At the moment they look like this:
[image]

But I would like them to look more like this so it actually looks like a toggle effect rather than 2 different buttons.

[image]

Heres the current code:

```css
.radio-toolbar-3 {
  margin: 1vw 1vw 1vw 0;
}

.radio-toolbar-3 label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #2E2E2E;
  width: 8vw;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.5vw;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.radio-toolbar-3 label:hover {
  background-color: #B4B4B4;
}

.radio-toolbar-3 input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #DAA521;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-toolbar-3">
  <input type="radio" id="classic" name="subscription-type" value="classic">
  <label for="classic">Classic</label>
  <input type="radio" id="adventurer" name="subscription-type" value="adventurer">
  <label for="adventurer">Adventurer</label>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

I've removed the border on the labels because this creates a line if you align them. I've also removed the standard `HTML` radio buttons. This caused a gap between the two labels so I gave them both a `margin-left: -30px;`. Lastly, I needed to align the two labels side by side. I gave the container a `display: flex;` and adjusted the width of the labels to `50%`.

```css
.radio-toolbar-3 {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.radio-toolbar-3 label {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: -30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.radio-toolbar-3 label:hover {
  background-color: #B4B4B4;
}

.radio-toolbar-3 input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #DAA521;
  color: white;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-toolbar-3">
  <input type="radio" id="classic" name="subscription-type" value="classic">
  <label for="classic">Classic</label>
  <input type="radio" id="adventurer" name="subscription-type" value="adventurer">
  <label for="adventurer">Adventurer</label>
</div>
```

Comment: add:
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
to the .radio-toolbar-3 Class and it looks very close to the example in the question

Comment: Thank you for your addition! I've changed my answer! @Warden330

Comment: @user10791031, is it possible to convert same structure in table format with 3-4 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
.radio-toolbar-3 {
    //margin: 1vw 1vw 1vw 0;  //remove this style
}
.radio-toolbar-3 label {
    color: #000; // add this
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    //border: 1px solid #2E2E2E; // remove this
    width: 8vw;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0.5vw;
    box-shadow: 0px 22px 19px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); //edit this
}
.radio-toolbar-3 label:hover {
    background-color: #B4B4B4;
}
.radio-toolbar-3 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #DAA521;
    color: white; //add this
}
```

Also using Button Groups from Bootstrap 4 might be great for you.

Comment: Please add a better explanation. Don't just say remove this and edit this, but show us what to edit it in to and if it needs to be removed why don't just remove it your self?